# Internet privacy, VPNs, etc. Am I anonymous?

Tags: privacy, ip, openvpn

I am a member of a forum that recently disabled my account because their system picked up another account from my household.  Anyways their terms of rectifying the situation are pretty invasive to my personal information so I'm wondering...

If I log on and create a new account while using my VPN is there still identifying pieces of data that could already be on my computer from previous logins that would give away my "new identity" as my "previous identity?"

Thanks!

Comment: A forum would not likely attempt to detect that, but it is possible in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies, local storage, cached data ... are still there and might be used to detect the same user. You can get rid of these (mostly) when using the private mode of the browser though. Browser fingerprinting is still possible though.